# Left invariant Haar measure of $\operatorname{Isom}(\mathbb H^n)$ and finite volume subsets of $\mathbb H^n$

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

(I have migrated this question from math.SE)

The isometry groups of the Riemannian manifolds $\mathbb E^n, \mathbb H^n$ and $\mathbb S^n$ all have Lie groups structures, so if $X$ is any of these Riemannian manifolds there exists a left invariant Haar measure $\mu$ on $\operatorname{Isom}(X)$.

I'm wondering whether the following holds:

> Fix any $x\in X$. Suppose $D\subseteq X$ is closed and has finite volume with respect to the metric of $X$. Then $$\mu\{\delta\in\operatorname{Isom}(X):\delta(x)\in D\}<\infty.$$

This of course holds for $X=\mathbb S^n$ since $S^n$ is compact.  This also holds for $X=\mathbb E^n$: this Lie group is isomorphic to $O(n)\rtimes \mathbb R^n$, we get that if $\mu$ is a left invariant Haar measure on $O(n)$, and since the operation in $O(n)\rtimes \mathbb R^n$ is given by $(A,b)\cdot(C,d)=(AC,Ad+b)$, then $\mu\times\lambda$ is left invariant, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb R^n$, and thus in this case our assertion holds.

However I haven't been able to prove this for $\mathbb H^n$. I guess a useful fact is that $\operatorname{Isom}(\mathbb H^n)$ is unimodular.

Comment: Yes. Indeed for $x\in X$ and $G$ the isometry group, up to rescale you can suppose that the measure on $X$ is the push-forward of the Haar measure of the Haar measure by the map $G\to X$, $g\mapsto gx$. So not only the value you're asking is finite, but equal to the measure of $D$. This works more generally for an arbitrary locally compact group $G$, compact subgroup $K$ with $X=G/K$.

Comment: @YCor  you mean the measure given by $m(A)=\operatorname{vol}(A(x))$? where $A(x)=\{\delta(x):\delta\in A\}$. I have already thought of this, but this is actually not a measure since it's not even additive.

Comment: No, what you're writing is not the push-forward. Given a measurable map $f:X\to Y$ between measurable spaces and a measure $\mu$ on $X$, the push-forward $f_*\mu$ is the measure on $Y$ defined by $(f_*\mu)(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A))$.

Comment: @YCor Could you please tell me why, up to rescale, we can suppose the measure on $X$ is the push-forward of the Haar measure on $G$?, I guess it has to do with the fact that both measures are invariant under the action of $G$.

Comment: Yes, the (left) $G$-invariant measures on each of $G$ and $G/K$ are unique up to rescaling, so the pushforward of the first is a scalar multiple of the second.